# Hibernate: @OneToMany (mappedby="abstractClass") doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate

**My problem:** I have abstract class C which I am trying to get one to Many relation:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "abstractAttachmentObject",targetEntity=Attachment.class)
```

but I get:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on ********.attachmentObject references an unknown entity: *****************.AbstractAttachmentObject
```

I tried different answers from older posts, but someone summarize that hibernate doesn't support this.
Is this problem solved now?

The code is so long but I can explain the main idea: I have one abstract class called abstractAttacmentObject which have 2 other classes A and B who inheriting it. This abstract class should have a relationship (one to many) with the class Attachment where one object of these classes can have many attachments

`

```
 @MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractAttachmentObject extends BaseEntity implements AttachmentObject{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "abstractAttachmentObject",targetEntity=Attachment.class)
    private List<Attachment> attachments ;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="ATTACHMENT")
public class Attachment extends BaseEntity{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="attachment_object_id")
    private AbstractAttachmentObject abstractAttachmentObject;
}
```

`

Comment: The error say that you need to put the @Entity on Attachment.class

Can you share the source code of this classes?

Comment: if you want only unidirectional remove `mappedby` attribute. Or bidirectional is required, in `Attachment` class defined relation back to `C` using `OneToOne or ManyToOne` annotation and property name must be `abstractAttachmentObject`.

Comment: I have @Entity on Attachment.class.

Comment: I did try to change the property name and to define ManytoOne. Still not working and I added some code as well :)